# JQuery POST request failing in IE8

Tags: jquery, post, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to send a post request when a user clicks a link.  The post request is supposed to override the default behavior (following the link).  It works fine when I try it in firefox or chrome, but fails in IE8.

```
  $('a.thought_delete').live('click', function(){
     $.post($(this).attr("href"), function(data){});
     return false;
  });
```

The request is triggered when I click the following link:

```
 <a href="thought/4/delete/" class="thought_delete">Delete</a>
```

I think the problem may be that the link I am posting to and the anchor's original href are the same.

This request seems to work fine - since the link is different.

```
 $('a.thought_delete').live('click', function(){
      $.post("/thought/2/delete/", function(data){});
      return false;
   });
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this problem?

Comment: What happens when you console.log (or debug or whatever) $(this).attr("href") ?

Comment: That seems to work fine - it shows up as "/thought/4/delete/".  I can successfully $.post anything except `$.post("/thought/4/delete/", function(data){});`

Comment: Your href seems to be missing a leading slash. If that does not solve the problem I would suggest using the lower level $.ajax() method. It gives you more granular control, and will let you catch errors more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You second parameter should be a map or string that is sent to the server with the request.

Your code is doing ... what exactly?

See the [jQuery POST api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more information and examples.

Comment: The application is a thought diary, and the code is supposed to let you delete a thought. I didn't want to implement it as a GET because I don't want thoughts to be deleted just by following a link, but the id of the thought is encoded in the href, so I don't actually need to add anything to the post statement.

Comment: I initially sent an empty dictionary along with the post, but removing it didn't seem to make a difference either way.

Comment: Adding a parameter for data - `$.post(href, "delete", function(data){});` - does seem to fix the problem, but based on the documentation it does look like this parameter is meant to be optional, and the $.post works fine without it as long as I use a different href.

Comment: Are you doing this just to do a confirmation for the delete?

Comment: Oh, no.  The post sends the signal to delete the thought, so if the post doesn't work, the thought doesn't get deleted.  Is that what you mean? Also, sadly the fix I suggested doesn't seem to work in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you clear the href before posting and restoring it afterwards?

```
$('a.thought_delete').live('click', function(){
  var href = $('a.thought_delete').attr('href');
  $.post("/thought/2/delete/", function(data){});
  $('a.thought_delete').attr('href', href);
  return false;
```

});

Comment: I tried storing the href in a var and then adding the line `$(this).attr('href', href)`, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to have fixed it.  Thanks for the suggestion though!